# Objective c - Move Small Circle inside a larger Circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to move a smaller circle inside a bigger circle and keep the smaller circle within the boundaries of the circumference of the larger circle.

This is what I have so far:

```
-(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (isJoystickToggle) {

        if(CGRectContainsPoint(joystickContainer.boundingBox, [self convertTouchToNodeSpaceAR:touch])){

            float posY = joystickContainer.position.y;
            float posX = joystickContainer.position.x;
            float y = joystickToggle.position.y;
            float x = joystickToggle.position.x;
            float angle = atan2f( y - posY , x - posX);

            double dx = (x-posX);
            double dy = (y-posY);
            double dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

            NSLog(@"%f",dist);


            if (dist < 60) {

                CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
                location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

                joystickToggle.position = location;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The larger circle height and width is 120 and the smaller circle width and height is 36.

### UPDATE

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

            if(CGRectContainsPoint(joystickToggle.boundingBox, [self convertTouchToNodeSpaceAR:touch])){
            isJoystickToggle = true;
            }

            return true;

        }

        -(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
            if (isJoystickToggle) {

            joystickToggle.position = ccp(64, 64);

            }
        }
```

Comment: What view is your larger circle and which view is your smaller circle?

Comment: What is, or isn't the code doing?

Comment: joystick container is the large circle and joystick toggle is the small circle they are both added to point ccp(68,68) the circle seems to stay in its bounds but when the distance reaches 60 i can't move the smaller circle which is joystick toggle because the distance reaches past 60

Comment: sorry the points of the circles are added at ccp(64,64)

Comment: If dist >= 60, do the reverse processing. You have the angle, and you know the max dist (60). So, using cosf(angle) and sinf(angle), you may get the wanted point position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Larme thank you, the small circle inside the large circle is working now:

```
-(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        if (isJoystickToggle) {


        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

        float posY = joystickContainer.position.y;
        float posX = joystickContainer.position.x;
        float y = location.y;
        float x = location.x;

        double dx = (x-posX);
        double dy = (y-posY);
        double dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

        NSLog(@"%f",dist);

        if (dist < 60) {

            joystickToggle.position = location;

        }

        if(dist >= 60){
            float angle = atan2f( y - posY , x - posX);

            float newx = (cos(angle) * 60) + posX;
            float newy = (sin(angle) * 60) + posY;

            location = ccp(newx, newy);
            joystickToggle.position = location;

        }

        }
    }
```